# 9patch behaving differently in background & image src

Tags: android, nine-patch

I am trying too create the following button:

[image]

Now this button will have some text inside so I created this 9 patch:

[image]

However when I create a button and put this as the background I get the following result:

[image]

Which somehow looks like not enough space is giving for the "borders" to show the proper curve on the button.

When I use the 9-patch as the source for an ImageView it's properly shown:

[image]

But then I cant put text on it and make it stretch with it.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `What am I doing wrong?` The right and lower (optional) marker areas indicate the **content area**. In your case, it is the text area. And... you cover everything, not leaving any padding!

Comment: tried that too with the same result!

Comment: Did you try completely removing the black markers on the right and lower sides?

Comment: Yes, I just tried that to no avail.

Comment: Now I have a doubt... which is your 9 patch file extension?

Comment: @Rotwang the extension is png

Comment: My suspect is confirmed. The extension for 9 patches has to be `.9.png`, not `.png`

Comment: @Rotwang the name of the file is .9.png. The extension is still png...

Comment: NO. The extension is `.9.png` that's why I asked. Strictly talking, the last dot determines the extension. But this is a *composite extension* and makes the difference. Anyway, that doesn't seem to be the problem. I never have problems with 9 patches, so I could try to make it for you. But, if I succeed, I have to post it as an answer.

Comment: Ok maybe we're taking thins too literally here. The name of the file is redbg.9.png